# Eclipse does not show Java Application run configurations

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 2018-09 with multiple Java Application run configurations. Below you can see, that I can run them by using the toolbar button. However, in the management view, they are not shown anymore. I already checked the filters. It also says, that it matches all run configurations using the filters at the bottom of the window. I also cannot create a new Java Application run configuration from this view. It simply does nothing when I click the "New launch configuration" button in case Java Application is selected. Any idea besides setting up Eclipse from the ground up (again)?

[image: Run from toolbar]
[image: Run configuratins window]

EDIT: I just downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse and opened the same workspace. It shows all Java Application run configurations just fine...

Comment: You could try closing Eclipse and deleting `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi` in your workspace. Often helps with weird issues like this.

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately this does not help